# Jquery Drag and Drop validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have most of the functionality working on a jQuery drag and drop quiz.

You can view it here: http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/ernst-young/2014/landingpage/

The user drags a word from the right and drop it in one of the gaps on the left.

My problem is i need some sort of validation that the correct word is dropped on the correct area.

I have added a unique class to each drag element (.wordX) and each drop element (.snapX)

I figured i could find the coordinates of the '.snap1' element using the jquery .offset method. Then have some sort of if statement saying only allow drop if the '.word1' .coordinates match. Otherwise revert back to the starting position.

But i have no idea how to right this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Current JS**

```
$(function() {
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ snap: ".snapTarget", snapMode: "inner", snapTolerance:
20, revert: "invalid" });
$( ".wordBg" ).droppable({
hoverClass: "boxHover",
});
});
```

**Current HTML structure**

**Dragable items:**

```
<div class="draggable word1">objectivity</div>
<div class="draggable word2">consult</div>
```

**Snap Targets:**

```
<span class="wordBg word6 snapTarget snap1"></span>
<span class="wordBg word6 snapTarget snap2"></span>
```

Comment: Try http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept, give each droppable an attribute like data-accepts="wordX" and use that when calling droppable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can certainly be improved but it shows how it works for the first sentence by using the accept option in the droppable element http://jsfiddle.net/pf34F/

```
$(".word6").droppable({
   accept: ".word6"
});
```

(described here: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept)

Comment: Great thanks, i actually came to the same answer late yesterday! thanks for helping :-)

Comment: You're welcome. It's a nice piece of code that I will need for my own projects :-)

Comment: Glad i could help you to, check back the link in a few days there will be lots more functionality :-)